# $\mathbb{R}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the cofinite topologies?

Tags: general-topology

Intuitively, you might expect the inverse image a cofinite set to be cofinite but what I'm struggling with is defining the bijection. I've looked around math.stackexchange for bijections from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ but most of them are overly complicated to me and I suspect the map is something much simpler.  Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two sets with the same cardinality are surely homeomorphic when endowed with the cofinite topology, because a bijection sends finite subsets into finite subsets.

An "explicit“ bijection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ might be defined, but it's a fact that, under the common axioms of set theory (including choice), a product of two infinite cardinals equals the largest one. So
$$
|\mathbb{R}^2|=|\mathbb{R}|\cdot|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}|
$$
and the two sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: hmm.. I don't really know enough about the axioms of set theory but intuitively it makes sense, so thanks!